# Using of DevExpress Grid (WinForms or WPF) in Dynamics AX

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, devexpress-windows-ui, devexpress-wpf

Do anybody use the DevExpress Grid in Dynamics AX?

If yes, my question is how to populate the data from a table to MainView & to Details view(s)?

I contacted DevExpress, but I got no answer except referencing back to Microsoft for documentation because AX is a Microsoft product.

Comment: Can you shed som light on the use case? Usually you do not use custom controls in AX. Maybe it be done using Managed host control, see https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/114925

Comment: @JanB.Kjeldsen
Thank you for your reply. Yes it could be done by using Managed Host. I know how to do it for other WinForms Controls. But in my case I just want to replace the Standard AX grid with DevExpress grid.
I add the grid as managed host and it shows in the form.. but it is empty. So as I said in the question. I need to populate the datasets to Main & Details views. How to do it? that is my question. As I said, I contacted DevExpress, the don't offer anything exept a link similar to your link which is not helpful in my case.